# Can I borrow more than Account Liquidity, from Compound Finance Protocol?

Tags: uniswap, defi, compound-protocol

I am working on an application that allows users to go Long/Short on ETH.
To go Long:

- Supply eth to Compound Protocol
- Borrow stable coin from Compound Protocol (against eth supplied)
- Buy eth on Uniswap with this borrowed stable coin
- hold until eth price goes up
- Sell eth on Uniswap, in exchange for stable coin
- Repay borrowed stable coin to Compound(along with borrow interest)
- Keep the difference(and interests earned on Compound) and profits
- Profits will be in stable coin (which can be exchanged)

My problem: After supplying ETH, when I borrow DAI and exchange it on Uniswap, I am able to do this multiple times even when the Borrow Balance exceeds the Liquidity.

My Smart Contract- https://github.com/Rushanksavant/Crypto-Long-Short-Trades/blob/main/contracts/contractLong.sol

JavaScript code(React, ethersjs):

```
import React from "react";
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
// import axios from 'axios'
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'
import contractLong from "../artifacts/contracts/contractLong.sol/contractLong.json"

import Nav from "../components/Nav";


const contractLong_add = "0x8f86403A4DE0BB5791fa46B8e795C547942fE4Cf";



export default function Long() {
const [supplyAmount, setSupplyAmount] = useState(0);

const [maxBorrow, setMaxBorrow] = useState(0);
const [borrowBalance, setBorrowBalance] = useState(0);
const [accLiquidity, setAccLiquidity] = useState(0);

const [contractBalance, setContractBalance] = useState(0);

let web3Modal;
let connection;
let provider;
let signer;

useEffect(() => {
    init()
}, [])

async function init() {
    web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
    connection = await web3Modal.connect()
    provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    signer = provider.getSigner()
}

async function supplyETH() {
    init()
    const Long = new ethers.Contract(contractLong_add, contractLong.abi, signer)
    let transaction = await Long.supply({ value: ethers.utils.parseEther(supplyAmount) })
    await transaction.wait()
}

async function goLong() {
    init()
    const Long = new ethers.Contract(contractLong_add, contractLong.abi, signer)
    await Long.goLong_ETH(parseInt(0.5 * maxBorrow), Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10)
}

async function get_info() {
    init()
    const Long = new ethers.Contract(contractLong_add, contractLong.abi, provider)
    setSupplyAmount(parseInt(await Long.callStatic.getSuppliedBalance()));
    setMaxBorrow(parseInt(await Long.callStatic.getMaxBorrow()))
    setBorrowBalance(parseInt(await Long.callStatic.getBorrowBalance()))
    setAccLiquidity(parseInt(await Long.callStatic.getAccountLiquidity()))
    setContractBalance(parseInt(await provider.getBalance(contractLong_add)))
    console.log(await Long.callStatic.getAccountLiquidity())
}

async function closePosition() {
    init()
    const Long = new ethers.Contract(contractLong_add, contractLong.abi, signer)
    let transaction = await Long.claimProfits(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10)
    await transaction.wait()
}
return (
    <div className="bg-gray-800">
        <Nav />
        <div className="flex lg:flex-row items-stretch justify-between lg:px-0 px-6 lg:py-20 py-8 2xl:mx-auto 2xl:container">
            <div className="z-30 relative lg:w-1/2">
                <div className="hidden relative dark:bg-gray-800 bg-black w-full lg:w-10/12 lg:h-full lg:flex justify-end items-center">
                    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/stock-market-investment-graph-on-financial-numbers-abstract-picture-id1372263450?k=20&m=1372263450&s=612x612&w=0&h=hsM29khQqyPRanTBQg_lSNdJfi9MsP97cC1zlZLKQho=" alt="image with decent chairs" className="w-full relative z-30 lg:h-full" />
                    <div className="w-3/4 absolute -right-20 z-30 px-6 py-10 bg-black h-5/6">
                        <button className="text-white text-2xl font-bold text-center underline lg:mb-3" onClick={get_info}>Live Status:</button><br></br>

                        <p className="text-white text-lg my-2 font-serif">Supplied Amount -</p><p className="text-yellow-500 text-lg my-2 font-serif">{supplyAmount}</p>
                        <p className="text-white text-lg my-2 font-serif">-----------------------</p>
                        <p className="text-white text-lg my-2 font-serif">Max Borrow -</p><p className="text-yellow-500 text-lg my-2 font-serif">{maxBorrow}</p>
                        <p className="text-white text-lg my-2 font-serif">Borrow Baalnce Current -</p><p className="text-yellow-500 text-lg my-2 font-serif">{borrowBalance}</p>
                        <p className="text-white text-lg my-2 font-serif">Account Liquidity -</p><p className="text-yellow-500 text-lg my-2 font-serif">{accLiquidity}</p>
                        <p className="text-white text-lg my-2 font-serif">-----------------------</p>
                        <p className="text-white text-lg my-2 font-serif">ETH holded -</p><p className="text-yellow-500 text-lg my-2 font-serif">{contractBalance}</p>

                    </div>
                    <div className="w-full lg:w-auto lg:-mr-32 lg:pl-20">
                        <div className="w-full relative z-30 lg:pl-5 px-6 py-20 bg-gray-800 lg:mt-10"></div>
                        <div className="w-full relative z-30 lg:pl-5 px-6 py-20 bg-gray-800 lg:pt-5"></div>
                        <div className="w-full relative z-30 lg:pl-5 px-6 py-20 bg-gray-800"></div>
                        <div className="w-full relative z-30 lg:pl-5 px-6 py-20 bg-gray-800 lg:mb-10"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="absolute top-0 dark:bg-gray-800 bg-black md:h-96 w-full hidden md:block lg:hidden"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="bg-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-800 lg:w-1/2 lg:ml-20 lg:p-14 p-8 flex shadow-lg">
                <div>
                    <h1 className="dark:text-white md:w-8/12 lg:w-10/12 xl:8/12 2xl:w-8/12 w-full xl:text-6xl sm:text-5xl text-4xl font-semibold text-gray-800 capitalize">LongETH</h1>
                    <p className="text-gray-800 text-lg my-3 font-serif">To supply ETH to Compound as collateral:</p>
                    <div className="mt-2">
                        <input className="w-20 h-10 mr-5 rounded-lg p-3 hover:bg-gray-100 border-double border-4 border-sky-500 border-gray-800"
                            onChange={(event) => setSupplyAmount(event.target.value)} />
                        <button className=" text-white bg-gray-900 hover:bg-black hover:text-white rounded-md p-4 "
                            onClick={supplyETH}>Supply</button>

                        <p className="text-gray-800 text-lg mt-20 mb-3 font-serif">Click below to go Long on ETH (*you need to Supply ETH before):</p>
                        <button className=" text-white bg-gray-900 hover:bg-black hover:text-white rounded-md p-4 mb-20"
                            onClick={goLong}>Take Position</button><br></br>

                        <p className="text-gray-800 text-lg mb-3 mt-15 font-serif">Click below to claim profits (*ETH price should be increased to get profits):</p>
                        <button className=" text-white bg-gray-900 hover:bg-black hover:text-white rounded-md p-4"
                            onClick={closePosition}>claim Profits</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

[image]

In the above image:

- Supplied Amount - Amount supplied from user->contract->compound protocol
- Max Borrow - Maximum Borrow possible(in USD), based on supplied amount
- Borrow Balance Current - Balance borrowed by contract from Compound
- Account Liquidity - Contract liquidity
- ETH held - Contract balance

Comment: The application is currently running on mainnet local fork(blockNumber: 12964900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getMaxBorrow` function returns a much smaller value than you think. The Compound protocol scales up token values so they are integers.

I think that you are borrowing 0.00000000000002173 DAI but you think that you are borrowing 2173 DAI. Try to scale up your value by the number of decimals in the DAI contract.

```js
unscaledAmount * Math.pow(10, 18);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam, this solved my issue